# Найти проверочные слова к "обедняет", "кормить", "угрожает", "занесение"

Tags: орфография

Какими словами можно проверить безударные гласные в словах 
"обедняет", "кормить", "угрожает", "занесение".

Comment: Влада, старайтесь писать свои вопросы  более подробно. И еще: домашние задания и на ресурсе обычно за учащихся не делают. Помочь - можем, если покажете, что начали что-то делать сами.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это домашнее задание,  человек не хочет думать.

Comment: Домашнее задание -  это еще не основание для закрытия. Плохо, что человек не дает своих вариантов решения, т.е. "не помоги мне", а "сделай за меня". Но тут тоже не закрывать надо, а заставить начать делать - и доложить, что не получается, в чем сомнение. Я так понимаю политику сообщества.

Answer (score 0):

кормить - корм, прикормка; угрожает - угроза; занесение - я занёс; обедняет - бедный

Answer (score 0):

Обедняет — бЕдность, бЕдненький, бЕдно, безбЕдно, худо-бЕдно.

Кормить — откОрм, откОрмленный, прикОрм, прикОрмленный, прокОрм, прокОрмленный, раскОрмленный, [волка ноги] кОрмят.

Угрожает — грОзный, грОзно, грОзность, грОзы.

Занесение — занёсший(ся), внёс, внёсший(ся), донёс, донёсший(ся), унёс, унёсший(ся).